# Disable cert revocation check in unix/linux using curl command

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

I am using `curl` command to invoke a rest service. It is as follows:

```
{curl -X POST --ssl-no-revoke --cacert xyz.pem -K urls.txt -H "Authorization:Basic XYZ" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @data.json}
```

The above command is used to hit the service using one way SSL and basic authorization. The data to be passed is enclosed in `data.json` file and the urls to be hit are enclosed in `urls.txt` file.

The above command works perfectly in Windows but when executed from linux, it says:

```
{curl: option --ssl-no-revoke: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information}
```

I want to disable certificate revocation checks altogether. It looks like `{--ssl-no-revoke}` works on Windows but not Unix/Linux.

Would like to know if any alternative.

Answer (score 8):

ssl-no-revoke is Windows Only. The only alternative I'm aware of is to have a valid certificate or not use SSL.

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 6):

Using a valid certificate is not always a solution as revocation checks will fail with a valid certificate too when there is no Internet connection (for example, in the presence of a captive portal).

One way is to disable certificate checking altogether, i.e.:

```
curl --insecure https://www.example.com
```

Note that this will greatly reduce the security as self signed certificates will also be accepted as well as revoked ones!